# Fastest way to read large files in java

Tags: java

What is the fastest way to read large file line by line ( file contains 1.000.000 lines) and parse some of lines in java? For example this a fragment of my file

```
INFO  00:02:12 - returning228885634                                                              
INFO  00:02:12 - Step is 1 for 228885634 statusOK duration 0.018               
INFO  00:02:12 - Step is 2 for 228885634 statusOK duration 1.55                            
INFO  00:02:13 - START executing FOR  test32967 at Mon Sep 23 00:02:13 GMT+00:00 2013       
INFO  00:02:13 - Currently working 7
```

And I want only to parse the test's id (32967) from this fragment!

Comment: Is the prefix always like `INFO  xx:yy:zz - START executing FOR  `?

Comment: do you anything about [threads](http://arashmd.blogspot.com/2013/06/java-threading.html)?

Comment: ppeterka No the prefixes can be different, for example test3620:1 OK 0.018

Answer (score 3):

You may try like this:-

```
try (SeekableByteChannel bytechanel= Files.newByteChannel(Paths.get("abc.txt"))) {
    ByteBuffer byte1 = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(1000);
    for(;;) {
        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
        int n = bytechanel.read(byte1);
        // some code
    }
}
```

Also look for **[java.nio.*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/package-summary.html)** packages

Comment: It would be interesting to know if this is faster than BufferedReader when you also take into account the line parsing needed.

Comment: What is the optimal way of doing the line parsing in nio?

Comment: @JonasKlemming:- Does that help to answer your query:- http://technicalmumbojumbo.wordpress.com/2011/03/17/file-io-old-io-or-nio-which-is-better/ ?

Comment: @JonasKlemming:- Also do let me know if I am missing something?

Comment: Can I seek to the concrete position in file with this method?

Comment: @user2842269:- Yes you can, check this:- http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JDK-7/RandomaccessIOusingtheSeekableByteChannel.htm

Comment: Fancy, but this works on bytes, not characters, and depending on your encoding, that may not be acceptable.

Comment: @Rahul Tripathi If you scroll down to the results on that page you linked to it shows single threaded BufferedReader is twice as fast as nio. Nio had some advantage in a multi-threaded setting.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to beat `BufferedReader` for things like this.

```
try {
  BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
  String line = null;
  while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    //do something with line
  }
} finally {
  try {
    reader.close();
  } catch (IOException e) {
  }
}
```

Comment: Your question says you want to read the file line by line. What do you mean by concrete position? A position in bytes or in lines?

Comment: in bytes, I have a binary search which returns that bytes position from where I want to start reading

Comment: And one more question, can I insert data by this method into HashTable?

Comment: I'm sorry, I think I've misunderstood your use case. If you want random access Rahuls answer might be closer to want you want.

Answer (score 1):

Use Guava's `Files.readLines()` method for which you can provide a `LineProcessor`.

```
Files.readLines(new File("a_file.ext"), Charsets.UTF_8, new LineProcessor<String>() {

    @Override
    public boolean processLine(String line) throws IOException {
        return line.contains("some identifier");
    }

    @Override
    public String getResult() { // the @tring here is the generic type of LineProcessor, change it to whatever
        //create a result, get your id or ids
        return "";
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To process large file you could make use of classes from new java package for treating IO `nio` package offer a variety of mechanism to manage this type of file with a considerably performance.

see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/package-summary.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java 8, you can try this using class Files and Streams.

For example:

```
Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get("somefile")).lines().map((t)-> r).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Also looks for [java.nio.files](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html) and others classes from [java.nio.*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/package-summary.html)